# Como comparar dois valores strings com pandas?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Olá!

Tenho dois dataframes do pandas e selecionei uma coluna de cada com ids. Eu quero comparar os ids para ver se o id de um dataframe está contido em outro, porém, não tem a mesma quantidade de linhas e não estão na mesma ordem.

Tentei comparar dessa forma

```
#Read data
import pandas as pd

cursos = pd.read_excel("planilha1.xlsx")
unidade_ensino = pd.read_excel("planilha2.xlsx", na_values=str)   
    
cursos = cursos.loc(cursos['codigo_unidade_ensino'] == unidade_ensino['cod_unidade_ensino'])
```

Porém, recebi o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 2):

Tente usando a função [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), desta forma:

```
mask = cursos['codigo_unidade_ensino'].isin(unidade_ensino['cod_unidade_ensino'])
cursos = cursos[mask].copy()
```